# how can i display the specific users of a database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

How can I display specific usernames of a database on oracle 10g using the sql*plus on console?
I have been looking for a link column on the following tables `v$database`, `all_users`, `dba_users`, `v$session`.

Comment: Do you want to list users currently connected, or all users which are defined in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To link V$SESSION and DBA_USERS, use "Usernanme" column from both the views. It'll return details on user session.

select D.USERNAME, D.USER_ID, V.SID, V.STATUS
from v$session v, dba_users d
where V.USERNAME=D.USERNAME;

If you need details about sessions created for background processes also, then join by "User#" from V$SESSION and "User_ID" from DBA_USERS.

select D.USERNAME, D.USER_ID, V.SID, V.STATUS
from v$session v, dba_users d
where V.USER#=D.USER_ID;

Answer (score 1):

To query users which are defined in the database, you can use the `all_users` view. For example, to select all users who start with `a` or `A`, use

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_users 
WHERE NLS_UPPER(username) LIKE 'A%';
```

To query current sessions for a particular user, you can use the `v$session` view. For example, to select all current sessions which are established for a user who starts with `a` or `A`, use

```
SELECT * 
FROM v$session
WHERE NLS_UPPER(username) LIKE 'A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select username from all_users;

or

select username from all_users where ...;
```

There are 3 different sets of views ALL_, DBA_, and USER_.

ALL_ views display all the information accessible to the current user, i.e. it can looks at all the shcemas the user has permissions to, DBA_ views display infor for the entire database and is intended only for admins. Then USER_ views display info from the schema of the current user.

Sounds like you need ALL_USERS